# Turn off beep of Xorg

Tags: xorg, x11, bell

How should I disable beep permanently? I know `xset b off` can do this, but what's the corresponding option in `xorg.conf`? Or any other way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few ways that you could achieve this permanently:

- You could add `xset b off` to your launch programs (if you are using `startx` or similar, this will be `~/.xinitrc`, otherwise for GNOME/KDE/etc, use your "startup programs" application)
- You could blacklist the module responsible for controlling the PC speaker (and thus also the PC beep), by adding `blacklist pcspkr` to a file called `/etc/modprobe.d/99-nobeep.conf` (or similar if your system is not Linux)
- If your system supports it, you could use your audio system to mute the PC beep (ALSA, PulseAudio, OSS, etc)

I do not believe that there is an option for this in `xorg.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, copied from http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-126746.html.

If you want it to not beep in console without going to the extreme of blacklisting the module for the speaker add this to `/etc/rc.local`

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6
do
setterm -blength 0 > /dev/tty$i
done
```

The other solution I've seen around is to add this to /etc/profile:

```
setterm -bfreq 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch it off permanently you should disable the corresponding modules in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist snd_pcsp
```

This is the default in many distros.